# Jquery - Create a LINK tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var doc=$("<tag><another><link>Hello</link></another></tag>");
console.log(doc.html());
```

Returns:

```
<another><link>Hello</another>
```

Expected:

```
<another><link>Hello</link></another>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/holden321/22DBU/

Comment: That's because _link_ is a void element.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link: _"As it is a void element, the start tag must be present and the end tag must not be present"_. The browser will sometimes fix invalid html for you.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you writing a XML?

Comment: Yes, I am. An xml string, to be precise.

Comment: @holden321 Try [$.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) instead.

Comment: @Jason P  It would be appropriate it I knew how to get the resulting xml string.

Answer (score 2):

The [link tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp) is used for defining a relationship between the document and an external source, for example a stylesheet. It is a void element and does not have a seperate closing tag.

If that's not the tag you're after, when you say link, do you mean to use the [anchor tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)?

Comment: No, I mean a simple tag which isn't defining anything, and which name is "link" :)